# Convert Received Data from SQL and Translate

Tags: php, mysqli

I am wanting to convert data that is queried from the database to another string. The best way I can explain what I'm trying to do is below:

I have a table called "users". Inside that table I have a column called "rank". Rank is a two-digit integer ranging from 1 to 21.

I want to convert that "1" or whichever number into more understandable text in my php file. So if your rank is set to "1", the output is "User" or what-have-you.

How do I go about doing this? I'm not sure what this process is called. I'm very new to php.

Thank you!

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: I can't post what I've tried if I don't know what to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a rank table having 2 columns, id and rank:

```
id   |   rank
-------------
1    |   user
2    |  admin
3    |   goof
```

Then JOIN the users table with the rank table:

```
SELECT u.name, r.rank
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN rank r
ON u.rank = r.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the ranks title in another table like mentioned by Jay Blanchard or you can define an array with the rank titles like this

```
$ranks = array(
    1   =>  'User',
    2   =>  'Administrator',
    3   =>  'Moderator'
);
```

and can echo like this

```
echo $ranks['rank_id_fetched_using_sql'];
```

rank_id_fetched_using_sql is supposed to be 1 to 21